# Get Mouse Wheel Scroll using Win32api in Python

Tags: python, winapi, mouseevent, pywin32, mousewheel

I want to read mouse wheel scroll events and then simulate them.
I know I can simulate it using below code.

```
#Scroll one up
win32api.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, x, y, 1, 0)

#Scroll one down
win32api.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, x, y, -1, 0)
```

However, I couldn't find a way to get whell scroll event using win32api in Python.
Is there any way to detect wheel scroll up or down events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the global `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message, you can use the [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) function and with `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook.

Then handle the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message in the hook function.

Here is a sample:

```
import win32api 
import win32con
import ctypes
from ctypes import windll, CFUNCTYPE, POINTER, c_int, c_void_p, byref

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

def LowLevelMouseProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    if wParam == win32con.WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        print("mousewheel triggerd!")
    return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_int, ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM, ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM)

    pointer = CMPFUNC(LowLevelMouseProc)
    hook_id = user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL,pointer,c_void_p(win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)
    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    while user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0) != 0:
        user32.TranslateMessage(msg)
        user32.DispatchMessageW(msg)
```

It works for me:

[image]

**Edit**

If there are problems like `<class'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert`, you can try the following code:

```
import win32api 
import win32con
import ctypes
from ctypes import windll, CFUNCTYPE, c_int, c_void_p, wintypes

 

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
user32.CallNextHookEx.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.HHOOK,c_int, ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM, ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM]

 

def LowLevelMouseProc(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    if wParam == win32con.WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        print("mousewheel triggerd!")
    return user32.CallNextHookEx(hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)

 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_int, ctypes.wintypes.WPARAM, ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM)
    user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = [c_int,CMPFUNC,ctypes.wintypes.HINSTANCE,ctypes.wintypes.DWORD]
    pointer = CMPFUNC(LowLevelMouseProc)
    hook_id = user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL,pointer,win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)
    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    while user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0) != 0:
        user32.TranslateMessage(msg)
        user32.DispatchMessageW(msg)
```

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Comment: How to distinguish up wheelscrolls and down wheelscrolls?

Comment: You should delete the 1st snippet, as it's  *Undefined Behavior* ([\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011)). 2nd is too, it works by luck (*TranslateMessage*, *DispatchMessageW*),